# what would indicate an overflow?

Tags: binary

[image]

Im doing this question and some clarification would be super helpful. What exactly would an overflow entail? If when converting to decimal notation an extra bit would be needed? Fro part 3 "consider the bits as two's complement numbers" does he mean find the 2's complement? Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For number 3 he does not mean find the 2's complement. He is telling you to treat the values as signed numbers using 2's complement notation. That would mean the first value in a) is positive and the other three are negative.

For overflow it is different for 2 and 3. For 2, unsigned numbers, overflow occurs if there is a carry out of the high bit. For 3, 2's complement signed numbers, overflow occurs if the sign of the result is not correct. For example, if you add two positive numbers and the result is negative, there was overflow.

Comment: what do you mean by high bit?

Comment: The high bit is the most significant bit.

Answer (score 2):

If you add *x* and *y* and get a result that is less than *x* or less than *y*, then the addition has overflowed (wrapped-around).

Answer (score 0):

An overflow would be if the resulting sum is a larger number than can be expressed in an 8 bit system. I believe that would be any number greater than 255 (1 << 8).

Your assumption "an extra bit" is mostly correct. In an 8 bit system, all numbers are stored in 8 bits. Any operation that results in a number greater than the maximum that can be represented will be an overflow. This doesn't happen when you convert to decimal, but when you actually perform the sum with the binary values. If all numbers are 8 bits, you can't just add an additional bit when you need to store a larger number.

Yes, "two's complement" is the same as "2's complement". I'm not aware of any distinction between whether you spell it out or use the numeral.